# How can I generate unique numerical IDs for agents created by three different sources in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have three sources that create agents and then flow into a queue. All three sources create different agents.
My idea is to assign an ID (numerical value of int) to each created agent in each source at "Actions - On before Arrival". The ID should be unique. So it should be prevented that the sources generate the same ID .
All ID coming from source 1,2,3 should be stored in the queue in a list after FIFO and output. To do this, I want to create a variable that can then store and output all the ID created.

Can someone help me and find a suitable code for the "source" which assigns an ID to each agent?

I have not managed to find a code that satisfies this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable of type `int` named `counter` next to the sources. In each source's "on at exit" code box, write:

```
counter++;
agent.set_p_MyID(counter);
```

this assumes all your agents created by the sources have a parameter of type `int` name `p_MyID`

With this universal counter, you will get unique ids.

Comment: thank you a lot for your help:) I still have a problem. I got the error message: The method set_p_MyID(counter) is undefined for the type "agent1"/ "agent2"/ "agent3". Do I need to additionally create a function named "set_p_MyID" in each agent or how do I solve that?

Comment: No, as per my message: "this assumes all your agents created by the sources have a parameter of type int name p_MyID". If this does not mean anything to you: what type of agents are your sources creating?

Comment: I am sorry, i accidentally created a variable instead of a paramter. Thank you a lot for your help!!!! Can I also ask you how I can now have ID read this list in my queue?

Comment: Please always open new questions in new issues, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow