# Calling elements in queue that were previously created in source

Tags: anylogic

I have three sources which create different types of "agents". In each source, an ID is assigned to each created agent.
The parameter of each agent is: p_MyID.
Now I want to output these IDs in the queue in the order they occur.

I would like to output all entries, in which order the IDs arrive in the queue. (FIFO)

What code do I have to enter in the queue at "On enter", so that I can output all entries?

Thank you a lot for your help!

i don't know where my IDs are stored and how to access them.

Comment: it relates to my first question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76313659/how-can-i-generate-unique-numerical-ids-for-agents-created-by-three-different-so

Answer (score 0):

> What code do I have to enter in the queue at "On enter", so that I can output all entries?

`traceln("agent "+agent.p_MyID+" arrived at time "+time());`

This will print your arrivals into the queue in the sequence that they arrived in

Comment: I got the error message: "p_MyID can not be resolved or is not a field".p_MyID is just a int parameter. What should I do? If I

Comment: then your agents flowing through the queue are not the right type (the type that has a p_MyID). You need to setup the queue block to expect those. Please do the step-by-step tutorials first, these are very fundamental basics to understand first :)